# ODP .NET TNS:no listener

Tags: .net, oracle, connection, odp.net, ora-12541

I'm currently trying to connect to an Oracle database. I can connect fine on my development machine, but when I deploy to my Win2k3 sp2 server I get the following error.

Faile to open connection... Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException ORA-12541: TNS:no liestener at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleErrorHelper(Int32 errCode, OracleConnection conn,  IntPtr opsErrCtx, OpoSqlValCtx* pOpoSqlValCtx, Object scr, String procedure, Boolean bCheck)

Any thoughts, ideas, instructions would be helpful.  I'm using Oracle.DataAccess.dll version 4.112.1.2.

Thanks

Comment: Not exactly clear on your configuration here. You've got a Oracle DB on system X. Your development machine can connect to X, but your new W2K3 server can't connect to X?

Comment: You're correct on the configuration.  My problem was that there was not an open connection between System X and my new W2K3 server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The actual issue was a firewall.

Apparently my local development machine had access to the server hosting Oracle, but my development Server did not. Once there was an open connection between the two servers, the TNS:no listener error went away.

This appears to have been a bogus error message returned by the Oracle Client.  The listener was there and my configuration (connection string) was valid, but there was no available connection what-so-ever between the two machines.

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same issue.  For some reason, it seems that using the "alias" was not working.

My `tnsnames.ora` file had something like this:

```
oracle =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = tcp)(HOST = myoracleserver.mydomain.com)(PORT = 1525))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = MYORACLESERVER)
    )
  )
```

I then changed my connection string's `Data Source` from (using the alias):

```
User Id=scott;Password=tiger;Data Source=oracle
```

To (not using the alias) :

```
User Id=scott;Password=tiger;Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=myoracleserver.mydomain.com)(PORT=1525)))CONNECT_DATA = (SID = MYORACLESERVER)))
```

Everything works flawlessly with [ODP.NET](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html) now.  It was and is still working with the alias when I use an old ADODB connection.

**UPDATE:**

ODP.NET cannot read your `tnsnames.ora` file *directly* from your app.  You need to tweak like I said in my answer or you can also specify where your `tnsnames.ora` file is in your `Web.Config` or `App.Config` file.

See [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33302087/771496) for more details about all options you have.

Comment: If placing the exact same TNS entry in the connect string solved your problem, that implies that you were not picking up the tnsnames.ora you thought you were. Search for multiple copies of it, and also check for TNS_ADMIN entries in your environment, machine.config, web.config/app.config.

Comment: I have `Data Source=oracle` in a Excel file with ADODB: works great. I have a console app with ADO.NET, it works using the method described in my answer. The Excel file still works. I am confused as to "where should I look ?" I just retested on 2 different computers... same result.

Comment: Search your whole machine for multiple copies of tnsnames.ora. Rename all but the one you want to test. Also check for TNS_ADMIN entries in your environment, machine.config, web.config/app.config. The point is, there are several ways TNSNAMES.ORA can be found when using ODP.NET and it is different than when using ADODB. You might be picking one up that is not the one you thought you were using.

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that the machine your TNSNames entry is pointing at does not have a listener running. Three different options I could see... (1) the entry is pointing a different machines in tnsnames.ora (different on both machines), (2) the DNS resolution is different between these two machines, or (3) the listener is listening on a different port possibly if there is one running on the machine.

Answer (score 0):

I learned another thing too. 
the TNSNAMES.ora file, inside Network\admin folder cannon have spaces at the beginning of the instances.

example:

```
MYORACLESERVER =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = tcp)(HOST = myoracleserver.mydomain.com)(PORT = 1525))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = MYORACLESERVER)
    )
  )
```