# NullreferenceException on OracleConnection.Open

Tags: c#, oracle, nullreferenceexception, odp.net

I am trying to connect to an Oracle Database with C#. For that I am trying to use ODP.NET since I found out that this should be the best way to do it.

Sadly I am getting a `NullReferenceException` as soon as I try to open the connection.

Stack trace:

> at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection.Open()
>
> at odptest.MyAddin.Initialize() in C:\ProgramData\SRH Systems\STARS\Projects\odptest\MyAddin.cs:line 28

And this is my code:

```
using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection())
{
    try
    {
        conn.ConnectionString = constr;
        conn.Open();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}
```

I am using the latest version of odp.net from here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/utilsoft-086879.html

I am realy confused, and even so I found some posts with the same problem, there was no solution offerd. I just need a simple SQL query from the DataBase and I don't know what the problem is.

Comment: Please post the entire stack-trace of your NRE. Also please don't `catch(Exception`, instead catch specific subclasses.

Comment: the catch is not the finished code, just a quick patch. it will be completed as soon as the connection is established

Comment: Ok, line 28. Are we supposed to guess which line that is?

Comment: These might help [1](https://community.oracle.com/thread/458801?start=0&tstart=0) and [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33264420/when-opening-an-oracle-connection-connection-object-is-null)

Comment: Line 28 is conn.Open();

Comment: are you sure that `constr` is not null?

Comment: @TimSchmelter I tried your suggestions, but those where threads I already found. I can connect to the db with other tools and I don't get any other exceptions other than the NRE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I don't know what I did exactly, but I reinstalled the Oracle Client 12c and now the connection is established as expected.

Answer (score 0):

If Login Id and Password is correct, re-start IIS. You might have re-started database service.